# Naming convention for objective c class

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, naming-conventions

I need to have classname in objective c as com.test.mobileapp.

Can anyone tell me if it is possible to write class name as com.test.mobileapp in objective c?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try and see what happens.

Comment: No, class names cannot have dots in them. However, I suspect this is an [X-Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/175984), so perhaps you would be better off describing the issue that you want to solve by naming the class with dots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use dot (.) in class name, not even in any variables, methods etc.

You can use :

`ComTestMobileApp` as class name.

If some reason you want to differentiate by a `.`(dot), then you can use some alphabet as :

`ComXTestXMobileApp`

even you can use underscore (but not a good way as breaks the naming conventions)

```
`Com_Test_MobileApp`
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as the class naming convention is concerned, using CamelCase is the best option according to coding standards. And the name should also give an idea of what the class is about or what is does.

As Anoop suggested, this way is the preferred way.

```
ComTestMobileApp
```